How to not lose current session in Ubuntu VM if there was network interruption?
I have two virtual machines (first is Windows and second is Ubuntu VM) which are configured using Hyper-V software.
I remote desktop to them using the default RDP application in Windows. When there is a network disruption, I can see that the windows go to Reconnecting to the session and retry 5 times. However, in the Ubuntu VM, I keep getting an internal error had occurred and then I will need to create another session to connect to the Ubuntu VM.
Is there a way to mimic how Windows tries 5 times to reconnect in Ubuntu VM?
